# Can't use google+ api to create post

Tags: php, json, api, google-api, google-plus

Here is my request and response

Request

```
{
 "object": {
  "originalContent": "post"
 },
 "access": {
  "items": [
   {
    "type": "domain"
   }
  ],
  "domainRestricted": true
 }
}
```

And response

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

Response status is 403 Forbidden

I have try this in https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities/insert

Comment: Add this scope while authenticating user : `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write`. Also user have to login with Google plus again and accept the scope. After that you will be allowed to use the API.

Comment: Note: Google+ domains is not Google+ the social media website.  You have tagged this Google+ social media yet you appear to be trying to Post to Google+ Domains.  which will only work with a Google+ domains account.   Which are you using?